# how to pass key and value in (onchange) event from cshtml page(view) to component(.ts) in angular2?

Tags: angular

```
<select class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.accountId" ngControl="account" #account="ngForm" (change)="onAccountChange($event,model)">
   <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Account</option>
   <option *ngFor="#acc of accounts"  [value]="acc.id">{{acc.name}}</option>
</select>
```

how to pass key and value in (onchange) - onAccountChange event ?

Comment: Just for the author's knowledge, writing a good title will help any future questions. You can check out this Meta Stack Exchange post for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title and this FAQ post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
<select class="form-control" required 
    [(ngModel)]="model.accountId" ngControl="account" 
    #account="ngForm" 
    (change)="onAccountChange($event,model, account.value)">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Account</option>
  <option *ngFor="#acc of accounts"  [value]="acc.id">{{acc.name}}</option>
</select>

accounts = [{id:1, 'name':"Pardeep"},{id:1, 'name':"jain"}]
onAccountChange(event, modal, id){
    for(let i=0; i<this.accounts.length ; i++){
      if(id == this.accounts[i].id)
        console.log(this.accounts[i].name);
    }
  }
```

I did't able to find out the exact solution but you could use this method to find out the name i.r key in the option(select) by using for loop over your object. like in the given example.

Comment: Passing key is my major concern rather than value? I shall get the value from $event.target.value

Comment: just give me a moment ill post the code or plnkr for key too.

Comment: Thank u pradeep Jain